# Loading HighStock with RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, highcharts

I have been trying to load highstock as a require module. I was wondering if anyone had managed to get this working? I am able to load highcharts as a require module and it works fine, but my shims for highstock are not working. I am getting a Highcharts.Stockchart is not a constructor error.

```
"highcharts": "../vendor/js/libs/highcharts",
"highstock": "../vendor/js/libs/highstock",

...

shim: {
// Put shims here.
"highcharts": {
    "exports": "Highcharts",
    "deps": [ "jquery"]
},

"highstock": {
    "exports": "StockChart",
    "deps": [ "jquery", "highcharts"]        
},
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this. I realize now that the Highcharts.Chart constructor and all features of Highcharts are included in Highstock so the Highcharts namespace was already defined.